# forward variances under rough bergomi

Tags: volatility, finance, finance-mathematics, stochastic-volatility, quantitative

I have seen in several papers on rough volatility using the following expression for the forward variances

$$ d\xi_t(u) = \xi_t(u) \eta \sqrt{2H} (u-t)^{H-1/2}dW_t $$

Can anyone explain to me how this is clear? Or point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe [this deck](https://mfe.baruch.cuny.edu/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/RoughVolatilityColumbia2018.pdf) by Jim Gatheral would help get the intuition, see slides 10 and following.

The dynamics you mentioned is obtained by:

- Looking at the Bergomi dynamics for the forward variance process;
- Assuming there is only one factor driving the dynamics;
- Noticing a similarity with a rough process when replacing the Bergomi exponential kernel by a Riemann-Liouville fBm kernel